# Getting all my projects with specific tag in Tags property

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I use EntityFramework on my ASP.NET MVC project.

Let's say I have the entity below:

```
public class Project 
{ 
    public int ProjectID { get; set; } 
    public string Description { get; set; } 
    public string Tags { get; set; } 
}
```

Lets say I have the following data in my DB:

```
ProjectID: 1 
Description: "My first element" 
Tags: "one, three, five, seven" 

ProjectID: 2 
Description: "My second element" 
Tags: "one, two, three, six" 

ProjectID: 3 
Description: "My third element" 
Tags: "two, three, four"
```

I would like to return all projects containing a specific number of tags. So for example I would like to get all projects with tags 'one' and 'three'. The list of tags to search for is dynamic and is stored in a variable like this: `searchFor = "one, three";`.

How can I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller create your ObjectContext entity object and call its method "Where"
example:
`db.Projects.Where(p => p.Tags.indexOf("one") > -1 && p.Tags.indexOf(three) > -1);`

And send it to the view as list.
example:

```
List projects = db.Projects.Where(p => p.Tags.IndexOf("one") > -1 && p.Tags.IndexOf(three) > -1).ToList();
return View(projects);
```

Comment: Thanks this is a good starting point. But as I told in my question the elements to search for are dynamic and stored in a variable (searchFor). So I don't think I can do my search in only one Where clause.

Comment: So, make a list of search strings and filter for all of them.

`string[] searchForList = searchFor.split(new char[]{',', ' '}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
List<Project> projects = db.Projects.ToList();
foreach(string sf in searchForList){
  projects = projects.Where(p => p.Tags.IndexOf(sf) > -1).ToList();
}
return View(projects);`